# ${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp apparently not recognized as a valid path in vscode tasks.json

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-code

When pressing ctrl+shift+b in my workspace folder, I'm getting `The terminal process terminated with exit code 1`. That seems to mean the path is incorrect. Yet, I'm following instructions from Microsoft over here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson

I also checked over stackoverflow and this should definitely work. When I replace *.cpp to main.cpp, it compiles without a problem. I have only one file right now but I will definitely have more in the future.

I am using vscode 1.44.2, g++ 9.3.0.

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "g++.exe build active file",
      "command": "D:\\cygwin64\\bin\\g++.exe",
      "args": [
        "-g",
        "${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp",
        "-o",
        "${workspaceFolder}\\BreadShopPro.exe"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "D:\\cygwin64\\bin"
      },
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$gcc"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: My workspace folder]

Comment: I'd still like a solution to this, but I've since started using CMake instead.

Answer (score 1):

Did you put a space between the name of any folder in the directory? Putting a space makes the directory invalid (i.e. "My Project" will not be recognized, but "MyProject" will). Seems like that may be the issue. I've faced the same issue and this fixed mine.